# Live USB for Ubuntu 15.10 keeps freezing

Tags: boot, nvidia, live-usb, intel-graphics, intel-wireless

Just as the title says, anytime I attempt to run the live USB for Ubuntu 15.10 on my computer, the OS will boot fine, but most of the time, the desktop will freeze permanently, usually after everything has loaded. The average time is typically 30 to 60 seconds after the desktop has loaded.

The md5sum for the .iso is correct, and the USB drive is not corrupt, as the OS booted fine on another computer.

This computer is a Toshiba Qosmio X75-A7290 laptop.

Specs are:

32 GB RAM

Intel Core i7 (4700MQ Haswell)

Intel HD Graphics 4600

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770M

256 GB SSD (Where Windows is installed)

1 TB HDD (for extraneous files)

Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230

I must note that not only Ubuntu has this problem. OpenSUSE and Fedora suffer from the same issue as well. Are any specs in this laptop contributing to this factor?

Thanks,
Fahad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found the solution. All I had to do was boot the live USB on both Ubuntu and Fedora with the `nomodeset`command for the boot option in GRUB.

I didn't need to change any settings in the BIOS.

This is where I found the instructions
[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076)